# Tidyverse not installing

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm having a bit of a pickle right now with the package tidyverse, that I need for an assignment on layering maps. I tried installing the package using `install.packages("tidyverse")` and `install.packages ("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)` but when I ran `library(tidyverse)` it wasn't installed. I searched online and found that I had an older version of RStudio IDE so I uploaded the latest version (1.3.1056).

After installing the newest version, I reinstalled the package but R tells me the following:

> "Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently
> installed".

So, I did it, but the R tells me Rtools package is not available for R version 3.5.3.

What can I do to use tidyverse?

Comment: The current R version is R 4.0.2.  Can you update your R version

Comment: Rtools is available for R-3.5.3, see https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html

Comment: So ... I suggest that you try to install `Rtools35.exe` from the link above, restart R, then try again `install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies=TRUE)`. If the compilation fails due to a problem finding Rtools, make sure you have uninstalled Rtools40, restart R and try again. If it still fails (and the problem is not due to not finding Rtools35), then please post your command and all errors in a code-block in your question. Thanks!

Comment: "Rtools" is not an R package. It is an additional tool used to compile packages. Though it's probably best to installed the pre-compiled versions for most systems. Using `install.packages("tidyverse", type="binary")` though that might only work for the latest version of R, and you are using a version that's several releases old.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions issue, try setting the directory for where you install R packages/libraries on your computer using libpaths. I have to do this on my work laptop because the university has it set up to store things like this in a tempporary directory on the remote server which isn't desirable.

```
.libPaths("C:/R")
.libPaths()
```